# Printing dynamic content with javascript

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, printing

**Problem**

We have page with form.
User fill the form and submit it.
I need to print page with data from form and some other content.

**Code #1**

```
$(document).ready(function($){
 $('input[name=sumb_but]').bind('click', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  var print_text = "<p>Test " + $('#form').serialize() + "</p>";
  var newWin = window.open('','printWindow','Toolbar=0,Location=0,Directories=0,Status=0,Menubar=0,Scrollbars=0,Resizable=0');
  newWin.document.body.innerHTML = print_text;
  newWin.print();
  });
});
```

Cool, **but**:

1. I need specific css
2. Print window appear before content was loaded... ooops

Ok!

**Code #2**

```
$(document).ready(function($){
 $('input[name=sumb_but]').bind('click', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  var print_text = "<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC '-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN' 'http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd'> <html xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml'> <head> <meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=windows-1251' /> <title>Оформление доверенности (простая письменная форма)</title> <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='/css/print_forms/warrant.css'> </head> <body> <p>Test " + $('#form').serialize() + "</p></body><script type='text/javascript'>window.print();</script></html>";
  var newWin = window.open('','printWindow','Toolbar=0,Location=0,Directories=0,Status=0,Menubar=0,Scrollbars=0,Resizable=0');
  newWin.document.write(print_text);
  });
});
```

1. document.write - in other case css not loading
2. At the and of content added "window.print()"

That works fine in all browsers, **but** not in IE - windows with content loading successfully without printing dialog.
I need help!
p.s.
CSS with media="print" - not good solution for this case for some reason.

Comment: What exactly does it do or not do in IE?

Comment: Page with content loading successfully. Post updated, snx

Comment: Try $(window).load instead of .ready. .load is onload, so this is the last thing that will fire.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function($){
 $('input[name=sumb_but]').bind('click', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  var print_text = "<p>Test " + $('#form').serialize() + "</p>";
  var newWin = window.open('','printWindow','Toolbar=0,Location=0,Directories=0,Status=0,Menubar=0,Scrollbars=0,Resizable=0');
  newWin.document.body.innerHTML = print_text;
  newWin.document.body.onload = function() { newWin.print(); }   

  });
});
```

this could help

Comment: In this case `newWin.document.body.innerHTML = print_text;` css not loaded.

Comment: as i can see you didn't added css, what you need is append head with css link and then put content into body, this is because when you put css link inside body its not loaded

Comment: Ok. I put full way to css file and css loaded. snx!